# Accessing XSL inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I may be asking a very basic question. I searched many posts but didn't find correct information. Please point me in the right direction.

Below is my scenario. I am using jQuery/Javascript, HTML, XSL.

I have some sample data in XML. The structure of the data looks like this

```
<information>
    <qContact>
        <name>TOM</name>
        <phone>612656656</phone>
        <email>tom@tom.com</email>
        <empId>1221212<empId>
    </qContact>
    <qContact>
        <name>SRAMK</name>
        <phone>566541042</phone>
        <email>abc@vnc.com</email>
        <empId>654212301<empId>
    </qContact>
    <!-- ... --->
</information>
```

I have table which d1isplays some of this information in a table which has a hyperlink/button "EDIT". So when user clicks on the edit button in the table, I need to populate the data in the textboxes/radio buttons, i have that in the XSL format.

I attached sample drawing of my screen: [image: screenshot]

I'm not sure how to access the XSL in jQuery or Javascript.
In html i was ablt to access, for example i'm iterating it like this.

```
<xsl:for-each select="/<xsl:for-each select="/information/qContact">">

<xsl:value-of select="name"/>
```

Here I have list of XSL nodes, i need one of them , suppose when user clicks on the mike row, I need to get the mike properties from XSL and set them in the text boxes.

Is it doable?

1. accessing the XSL in jQuery
2. iterating through the particular node in this case `<qContact>` (and then getting name,email,phone etc)?

Please help me.

---

Some more Information:

1) I use Html to create different fields[text, radio buttons etc]

2)When i save the data in database and when reloading the form, i put that data in XSL and access it in the html  page.

example:

```
<td><input id="empName" type="text" name="name" value="{/information/qContact/name}" /></td>
```

3) I can access it inside jquery also.

Example:

```
 console.log("<xsl:value-of select="/information/qContact/name>");
```

Problem Scenario:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/information/qContact">

<a href="#" onclick="edit('Generated','{ID}','{current()}');event.returnValue=false; return false;">Edit</a>

</xsl:for-each>

function edit(name,id,selectData){
                    console.log("Srikanth");
                    console.log(selectData); // This is printing all the data inside it.
                    console.log("<xsl:value-of select="/information/name"/>"); // Not able to access like this
                    $('#name').val('<xsl:value-of select="/information/qContact/name"/>');// Not able to access like this
                    $('#email').val('<xsl:value-of select="/information/qContact/email"/>');// Not able to access like this
                    console.log(id);

            }
```

---

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you need XSL for? How do you run it, exactly?

Comment: Edited the post, Please let me know, if you are not understanding my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Question title is **Accessing XSL inside jQuery**
The short answer is: You can't. You can execute xslt with `transformNode` (depending on browser).

But this is not really what you like to do.
Keep in mind that there are three step involved.

- loading xml and xsl and generating html (with JS)
- loading (interpreting the generated html) -  The xml and xslt is not accessible any more (at least not like you do).
- execute the onclick handler

Your generated link will look something like:

```
   < a href="#" onclick="edit('Generated','','
      TOM
      612656656
      tom@tom.com
    1221212
  ');event.returnValue=false; return false;">Edit</a>
```

Therefor you need to generate a html or JavaScript representation  of the required data.

For example generate a JS object with name `{name: 'TOM'}`:

```
<a href="#" 
       onclick="edit('Generated','{ID}',{{ name: '{name}' }});event.returnValue=false; return false;">Edit</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like this way i can solve my problem.

How to add more attributes here? I mean if i want to pass email also in the onclick then?

<a href="#" 
       onclick="edit('Generated','{ID}',{{ name: '{name}' },email:'{email}});event.returnValue=false; return false;">Edit</a>

This is how i need to do?

how can i access email and phone number in edit method.

And will there be any change in the syntax of the function.

function edit(title,source,name){
}
I'm seeing this error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is not defined. In the browser console.

Comment: The right syntax to add email would be `{{ name: '{name}', email: '{email}' }}` The third  parameter of edit()  will be an object now.  Try log `selectData.name` or  `selectData.email`

Comment: Glad I could help.Could you please select the answer as valid.